# Is it safe to store a user's username on storage?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-router

Is it safe/reasonable to store a users username in localStorage or a React state when a user logs in?

I currently have a simple `<Login/>` form that only renders and displays if a user is not logged in. When a user logs in, a jwt token is sent from the server, the token is stored in localStorage and saved in a React state inside `<App/>`.

If there is no token inside the React state 'token', then the  component renders, however if there is a token (meaning a user logged in, the token was set to the React state and local storage), I would like a  component to render instead of

I am using react-router-dom to handle routing in my application.

My main question is whether I should send the users username alongside the token, and store that somewhere? I ask this because I would like to load the `<Profile/>` component with the users username and to the route `/user/:username` once they logged in. However I have no idea how else I would do this, because once I save the token and once they are logged in, how would I be able to redirect them to their `user/:theirusername` url instantly after login if I do not have their username. Would I need to somehow refetch their data with a graphQL "ME" query?

Answer (score 0):

It greatly depends on the kind of application you are working on, But storing a username in the localstorage can be made safer by having a hashing function that encrypts the user name before storing it to localstorage, In this case someone will not know the username by just looking into the storage values but someone can only read it if they can reverse the encryption.